# I would like to make 5 character after first hypen(-) bigger than the rest of the sentence in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am newbie in this crystal report. I would like to change the **font size to be 5mm** in this 0U482 in the sample data below:

82115-0U482-MA 000002

From searching the google and study in internet, this is what I found to do it. But I'm not sure how to make it working for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

1. Make a new formula called modelno1 to find the word after first -
2. Code this into the new formula `left({modelno},(len({modelno})-InStr({modelno},"-"))+1)`
3. Make another formula called modelno2 to get only 5 character only from previous formula
4. Code this into modelno2 `left({@modelno1},5)`
5. Make the font size to 5mm
6. The code for font size is `stringVar modelno1 := '<b style="font-size:5mm";>'@modelno2'<b>'`

Sorry if my English is bad.

Thank you

Comment: Which step did not work?

Comment: The 6th step sir.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, 
I managed to make the code work as I want. 
Thank you God.

The solution is:

Change the 6th step code into 
`'<b style="font-size:5mm";>'&left({@modelno2},5)&'</b>'`

Change the **paragraph formatting** in the formula field to **HTML Interpretation**.

You should be good to go!
Cheers